# Where can I find jazz piano scales to practice?

Tags: piano, learning, scales, jazz

I played the piano for years classically when I was younger, but eventually left it alone in my late teens and twenties. I probably wouldn't have if I'd been allowed to do more Jazz as I always wanted to.

I'm just wondering where I can get hold of the scores of good Jazz scales to practice? I'm sure there are many different types but I don't know enough about it to even look!

Comment: [This question](http://music.stackexchange.com/questions/410/how-can-a-classical-pianist-learn-jazz-piano) is at least related, in particular the part about "The Real Book" volumes (the copies I have do not offer scales, but I don't think deducing them from the tons of nice songs they offer should be a problem). I'm not commenting about the "The Jazz Piano Book" because I don't know it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "Scale Syllabus" page inside any [Jamey Aebersold](http://www.jazzbooks.com/) book is a good resource.

And how about that, you can get it for [free from his website](http://www.jazzbooks.com/mm5/merchant.mvc?Screen=FREE&Store_Code=JAJAZZ) in PDF format:

**[Scale Syllabus](http://www.jazzbooks.com/mm5/download/FREE-scale-syllabus.pdf)**